# SSIS Error - [XML Task] Error: Cannot get encoding from XML when source is a variable

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis, etl

I have an issue with an XML Validation task in SSIS. When I hard code a file connection to an XML file specifically, everything runs fine. If I attempt to use a variable as the source for the XML file, I get an error when my SSIS package runs.

> [XML Task] Error: Cannot get encoding from XML.

Something must be different, of course.

My over-riding issue is that I have three files in a folder I want to validate, once each, and in turn, so a hardcoded connection to a particular file is no good. I want to avoid creating a copy of the actual xml file with the name of tempXML.xml for example, connecting and validating it, and deleting it each time I'm finished validating. That would do as a workaround, but it seems what I want to do should be fairly straight forward, except... I can't see how!

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

So I found this:

The Input variable needs to actually contain the xml. You are passing in the path to the XML

This appears to be my problem.